# Pandas: multiple condition to strings

Tags: python, pandas

I try to change my dataframe.
Usually I use something like

```
df1= df[df.url.str.contains("avito.ru/*/telefony/")]
```

But if I want a lot of condition?
I want to write to `contains` more than 100 strings.
How can I do that?

Dataframe

```
анонс кинофильмов 2016
анонс кинофильмов 2016
"выборок имеют величину момента сопротивления"
"выборок имеют величину момента сопротивления"
ансамбль 9 человек
ансамбль 9 человек
ансамбль 9 человек
"Времена года в музыке, литературе, живописи"
"Времена года в музыке, литературе, живописи"
"Времена года в музыке, литературе, живописи"
apple iphone
samsumg
facebook
None
None
None
```

And some words from list

```
lst = ['iphone', 'sony', 'alcatel', 'galaxy', 'samsumg]
```

Desire output

```
apple iphone
samsumg
None
None
None
```

I mean if some words don't contain in str, I want to delete that. (But values with None I want to have there too).

Comment: Sorry are you this user: http://stackoverflow.com/users/6065920/ldevyataykina? as this question is really similar to that user's questions

Comment: Also your question is a little unclear are you looking for matching all 100 strings or are you looking for any strings that match any of the 100 strings?

Comment: @EdChum I add desire output

Comment: You can create a search string by doing `'|'.join(lst)` and pass this to `str.contains`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a pattern by joining `|` with all your list items and pass this to `str.contains`:

```
In [31]:
lst = ['iphone', 'sony', 'alcatel', 'galaxy', 'samsumg','None']
pat = '|'.join(lst)
df[df['url'].str.contains(pat)]

Out[31]:
             url
10  apple iphone
11       samsumg
13          None
14          None
15          None
```

To handle the missing values include `pd.isNull(df['url'])` in the boolean condition:

```
In [54]:
lst = ['iphone', 'sony', 'alcatel', 'galaxy', 'samsumg']
pat = '|'.join(lst)
df[pd.isnull(df['url']) | df['url'].str.contains(pat) ]

Out[54]:
             url
10  apple iphone
11       samsumg
13           NaN
14           NaN
15           NaN
```

Comment: But how can I don't loose values with None?

Comment: Are those values string 'None' or are they really `NaN` None? it's unclear from your question

Comment: They are empty and I want to save that

Comment: Please don't send me error codes, edit your question with raw data, code and errors that reproduces the errors, what you posted is still ambiguous

Comment: What do you mean empty strings or `NaN`? do you understand the difference? Also post raw data that correctly reproduces your df, at the moment it looks like the string 'None' which is completely different

Comment: `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values` I get this with your code

Comment: See updated answer, if this still doesn't work then you need to include raw data to accurately reproduce your df like I've asked you many times